# Why scroll to section doesen't work? Why scroll to section scrolling to up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I scroll down and click links scroll goes up but I want the scroll to section (little dawn not up)

[image]

Comment: Please provide some kind of code.

Comment: look: http://jsfiddle.net/hq4jg2mu/2/

Comment: I have conflict with easyTabs

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are looking to create a link that points to a specific section in the page

You first need to create a a section and give it an ID

For example, 
`<div id="my-section">Your content goes here</div>`

Next, you need to create an anchor tag that points to this section. Give the section ID in the `href` attribute, as shown below
`<a href="#my-section">Lnk to section</a>`

This should work for you

Comment: Look at my fiddle. I have conflict with EasyTabs: http://jsfiddle.net/hq4jg2mu/2/

Comment: This almost works but still scroll to top before: http://jsfiddle.net/hq4jg2mu/3/

Comment: This CSS code was causing the isuue `.odstep {height:500px;}`
I  commented this out and your fiddle works fine .

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fix that with this code:

```
$('.tab a').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top + 500
}, 1000);
return false; });
```